# Mail failure - rejected by local scanning code

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

i was sending mail from my server ip is completely new and tested . thhe mail i am sending is html mail but not a single mail is getting delivered in my webmail i am getting this error

A message that you sent was rejected by the local scanning code that
checks incoming messages on this system. The following error was given:

This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered

------ This is a copy of your message, including all the headers. ------

i tried disabling spamassisn but no luck .

i searched everywhere did several changes in whm tweak settings but all mails are going in not even spam all are being rejected by server

Comment: Do you try to delver the email to YOUR server or someone else's one?

Comment: @VladimirKolesnikov other server but other server is not rejecting mail.its our local filter which is detecting it as spam and further processing it stops

Comment: @james This is very late to the party I know, but did you find a simple resolution for this in the end? Was it definitely the sending server that was blocking it, not the receiving? I appear to have the exact same issue that only started a couple of weeks ago..